# Property Expansion in Xpath Assertion declare namespace in SoapUI

Tags: soapui, assertions

I am using xpath match assertion in soapui and there is used

`declare namespace ns1='http://1.1.1.1/something/something';`

But I often need to change IP address in many assertions so I tried to use something like this but it is not working... Can I somehow use ip adress from project property?

`declare namespace ns1= ('${#Project#hostGet}/something/something');`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible to use Property Expansion while declaring the namespaces in the Xpath Assertions.

You are almost there, just trivial error.

Change from:

```
declare namespace ns1= ('${#Project#hostGet}/something/something');
```

To:

```
declare namespace ns1= '${#Project#hostGet}/something/something';
```

[image]

And hoping that you know to define the custom property `hostGet` and its value at Project level.

Comment: Thank you, working fine now :) I had also mistake in property there was also port in property with IP adress... :/ thanks

Comment: Appreciate if you accept it as answered and upvote then.